# bad data in struct from arduino to raspberry pi

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am trying to send a struct from arduino to a raspberry pi over a nrf24l01 radio module.

for example on the arduino side:

```
typedef struct{
    uint8_t id;
}payload;

payload pay;

pay.id = 8;

radio.write(&pay, sizeof(pay));
```

then on the raspberry pi side:

```
typedef struct{
    uint8_t id;
}payload;

payload pay;

radio.read(&pay, sizeof(pay));

printf("%d",  pay.id);
```

when i send an id of 0 to 7 then it shows fine on the Pi.  if i send 8 then the Pi shows 12 ... and so on.

i would assume this has something to do with the representation of the data on the arduino vs. the Pi (arduino being 8 bit and the pi not) however i'm not sure what is actually happening in this case and what needs to be done about it.

The Pi is using Raspian for its OS.

Comment: Try sending and receiving `pay.id` and tell us what's the result.

Comment: if i do this for example uint16_t x = 11;
      radio.write( &x, sizeof(x)) i get 15 on the other side.

Comment: its pretty strange ... heres some pairs of numbers representing what was sent and what was received .. 7->7 ,  8->12, 9->13, 10->15, 11->15,  12->14 , 13->15

Comment: what do you get for `sizeof` of the struct in Arduino and Pi?

Comment: same on both sides. 2.

Comment: I assume you are working on somthing like [this](http://hack.lenotta.com/arduino-raspberry-pi-switching-light-with-nrf24l01/). Make sure your pins are well connected, specially the Gnd pin, on both Arduino and Pi boards. I've had issues in the past with this. The errors seem pretty random to me. Do you get always the same results in numbering? like the sequence you described before?